# How to display images from strapi wysiwyg markdown editor to angular frontend

Tags: angular, proxy, markdown, strapi, image-upload

So I figured I'll answer this question as I had searched for a while and found nothing.

Scenario ([Angular](https://angular.io/) frontend and [Strapi](https://strapi.io/) backend):

I have blog posts that contain text and images, and I am trying to display the images on my website as they are stored in markdown on strapi.

example of what the image path in markdown looks like

```markdown
![beautiful-picture.jpg](/uploads/beautiful_picture.jpg)
```

The problem is that on the frontend, this path resolves to

```
http://localhost:4200/uploads/beautiful_picture.jpg
```

whereas the image is actually here

```
http://localhost:1337/uploads/beautiful_picture.jpg
```

How can I configure my angular frontend app to use the strapi backend URL when creating image URLs without having to manually copy the backend `uploads` folder into my frontend `src` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I had to use [Angular proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server), note that this can be used for both local and remote servers.

For example, to divert all calls for `http://localhost:4200/uploads` to your backend strapi server running on `http://localhost:1337/uploads`, take the following steps.

1. Create a file `proxy.conf.json` in your project's `src/` folder.
2. Add the following content to the new proxy file:

```json
{
  "/uploads": {
    "target": "http://localhost:1337",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

3. In the CLI configuration file, `angular.json`, add the `proxyConfig` option to the `serve` target:

```json
...
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
            }
          },
...
```

4. Make sure to stop the development server if it's already running and type `ng serve` to boot up the dev server again.
5. Back in your browser, you should now see the images displayed within the text.
6. Visit [Angular proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) to read more.
7. bonus tip: you can use [ngx-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown) to display markdown content in your angular template.

Comment: Do you know how we coud achieve this in a NextJS application ?

Comment: Do you mean NextJS with the Strapi backend? I am not sure as I haven’t tried it out yet with another framework, but maybe you check the strapi docs or check out this link that covers proxy with NextJS. 
https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-proxy-next-js/